# "Connection interrupted" Communications error on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, ios10, sdwebimage

Can any one help me to figure out the following error I get when I run my application?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        customCell.selectionStyle = .none
        let dictionaryAtIndex = contentArray[indexPath.row] as Dictionary <String, Any>

        customCell.activityIndicator .isHidden = false
        customCell.activityIndicator .startAnimating()
        customCell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL!), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            customCell.activityIndicator .stopAnimating()
            customCell.activityIndicator .isHidden = true
            print("image downloaded %@",image ?? "")
        })
    return customCell
}
```

It's crashing every time when I am scrolling.Getting Communications error:  { count = 1, contents = "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" } }> Xcode 7 (iOS 9) Communications error:  .Please help me at the earliest.

Comment: can you try loading a local image? ... just for test

Answer (score 0):

From this line `customCell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL!)`, the crash is likely to be because you were trying to load either a very large image or a great number of images using `SDWebImage`. My recommendation is to download all the images beforehand on background, save them to your document folder and then load them up to you `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are overloading the the SDWebImage downloader.

You can try to tweak the image downloader changing the max number of the concurrent downloads or the download timeout

in Swift 3 (SDWebImage V 4.0.0)

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().imageDownloader?.maxConcurrentDownloads = yourValue

SDWebImageManager.shared().imageDownloader?.downloadTimeout = yourTimeout
```

Comment: It doesn't have any problem in iOS 10 or later .The problem is arising only in iOS version below 10.

Comment: XPC is Apple's inter-process communication (IPC) system. Some functionality (probably related to the image downloading) is handled by a separate daemon - that runs in background.

Connection interrupted means that the IPC connection was interrupted for some reason. Perhaps it took too long, perhaps the timing was just bad and the daemon or your app needed to urgently do something else. 
This system is provided by the OS. So I am not surprised that it is happening only on a specific version.

Comment: Can you verify the amount of memory used by your application? If your system is running out of memory the it could generate this kind of issues.

Comment: it's 53 MB in size and still 10.2 gb free space is available .

Comment: You should verify the memory use by the application during the execution not the size of the application itself. You can gather this information using memory profiling tool provided by XCode Debug navigator